# How to use Media query syntax for Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, media-queries, width

I am working in react js project in which I want to distinguish between Medium Screens OR Big Screen OR Small Screen using the below breakpoints

```
// Small
@media (max-width: 575px) {}

// Medium
@media (max-width: 990px) {}

// Big
@media {}
```

Can anyone help by updating this pseudocode https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cu8xqj?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 1):

I use stylesheets for resposiveness - specifically the preprocessor Sass. Has a React package and everything. If this works for you, you can use a simple mixins file and import it in any other scss files you might be working in.

In your mixins.scss file:

```
@mixin tablet {
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin desktop {
  @media (min-width: 1280px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

And then in any other SCSS files where you want to use those breakpoints:

```
@use "../../styles/partials/mixins" as *;

.class {
   @include desktop {
     display: flex;
   }
}
```

This won't be applicable if you are trying to execute JS code upon changing breakpoints. I have an example of that I can dig up if need be.